# Screen goes crazy after installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

A bit of backstory. Since the Windows 10 beta has come out, I have installed and uninstalled the software twice, and if things continue and I am not able to fix this issue, i will be uninstalling it 3 times.

The issue is that my screen will do this at will for anywhere from 5 to 15 seconds at a time with no real usual time between them.
[image]
[image]

Before you go shouting "This is a hardware problem!", please read this list of incredibly odd circumstances that lead up to this issue.

1. This *only* happens on Windows 10. I have gone back to windows 7 many times and the issue is immediately resolved. This basically rules out a hardware issue.
2. It never happens within 24 hours of installing Windows 10. It *always* begins the next morning. (Only from observation. This may not actually be true)
3. I have 2 graphics systems, an Intel HD 3000 and an Nvidia GeForce 525M. *both* graphics systems do this. I have disabled one or the other and had it happens on both.

I am completely dumbfounded on trying to figure out what could be causing this. Anyone know something I don't?

Happy to answer questions in the comments.

Comment: If you are going to downvote this, explain why. There is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what causes this although there is no good way to stop it right now.

This laptop has a dell driver that holds additional controls over the screen such as brightness and a button to turn off the screen temporarily. Pressing the button that turns the display off immediately fixes the episode, which leads me to believe dell is responsible. Disabling the driver keeps my screen stuck at full brightness, so that isn't an option. I have a few choice words for them...